# Change the Time of Monitor's Waiting while Mac Mini's Wake Up

Tags: sleep-wake, display, mac-mini, notifications

I have a Mac Mini so, as every other Mac Mini owner, I have an other-brand monitor. But Apple, is used to use their integrated monitors that wake up from sleep quickly.

My LG monitor is a very good monitor but it's slower than Apple's monitor waking up so, every time I wake up my Mac, monitor wake up just in time to show me all notifications, received while mac was sleeping, disappearing from screen because they were already displayed for 5 seconds from Mac's woke up, while monitor was turning on!

So is there a way to Change the time setted from Apple between Mac's and monitor's wake up times? (a terminal string or something else)

Comment: I don't see the delay you are talking about, and I am using a Dell monitor (with both a mini and a Mac Pro). Does the monitor have a similar delay when waking from other sources, such as a Windows PC?

Comment: ...I don't know, I've never used it with other sources, but I don't think my monitor is an Apple hater! Probably Dell's monitor as faster woking up...